# Javascript / Google Analytics - Simplify Javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pagespeed

We are trying to reduce the javascript load and cleanup a page to improve the pagespeed score and generally make the page faster.

We have some Google Analytics code that looks like this:

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-374943-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'<?php echo $trackpage_variable; ?>]);
 
   (function() {
     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

</script>
```

Someone cleaned up the code and removed the entire function, so the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-374943-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'<?php echo $trackpage_variable; ?>]);
</script>
```

However, our Google Analytics stopped reporting as a result.

Is there a better way to clean this code up and get rid of the g.doubleclick.net/dc.js reference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That reference is the ga tracking code. It's not going to work if you don't include it. You could bundle it into your source, but given that this is being loaded into a php template, that seems dicey. You could add a check (or check manually) to make sure it only executes once, other than that I don't see any great optimizations to be made.

Comment: Given that Google, presumably, periodically update the client-side portion of GA, bundling a specific version seems exceptionally fragile.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use Google Analytics without loading Google Analytics.

> ```
> ga.async = true;
> ```

It’s already designed to load asynchronously, so it doesn’t block rendering.

Leave it alone.